# How can I enable project tango in Normal camera mode and take 3D depth data?

Tags: java, android, image, android-camera, google-project-tango

I want to take the snap of an object and get the 3D coordinates of the respective pixels of that snap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tango provides a set of examples to do the exact same thing:

Unity AR example: https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-unity/tree/master/UnityExamples

Java AR example: https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-java/tree/master/AugmentedRealitySample

C++ AR plane finding example: https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-c/tree/master/plane-fitting-jni-example